# Karma/Jasmine how to call a method on an angularjs Factory

Tags: karma-jasmine, jasmine2.0, gulp-karma

I need some help getting this test to run. I've spent way to much time on it.

So i am stuck and need some help?

I simply have a factory method, that has one method and i keep getting [Unable to get property 'method1' of undefined or null reference ] errors from Karma.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var first = function () {
        var method1 = function () {
            return 'yes';
        };
        return {
            method1: method1
        };
    };
    angular.module('app').factory('first', [first]);
})();
```

and here are my attempts to call method1.

```
describe('Test Suite', function () {

    describe('Factory Test', function () {
        beforeEach(function () {
            module('app');
        });

        var service;

        //beforeEach(inject(function (_first_) {
        //    service = _first_;
        //     console.log(JSON.stringify(_first_, null, 4));
        //}));

        beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
            service = $injector.get('first');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(service, null, 4));
        }));

        //beforeEach(function () {
        //    angular.mock.inject(function ($injector) {
        //        service = $injector.get('first');
        //    })
        //});

        describe('calling method1', function () {
            var output = service.method1();
            expect(output).toBe('yes');
        });
    });
});
```

and my output from Karma

```
IE 11.0.0 (Windows 10 0.0.0) Test Suite Factory Test calling method1 encountered a declaration exception FAILED
TypeError: Unable to get property 'method1' of undefined or null reference
   at Anonymous function (tests/firstTest.spec.js:31:13)
   at Anonymous function (tests/firstTest.spec.js:30:9)
   at Anonymous function (tests/firstTest.spec.js:4:5)
IE 11.0.0 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.135 secs)
IE 11.0.0 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.14 secs / 0.135 secs)
```

Answer (score 0):

argh, stupid me.

I forgot to add the it("", function(){}) stuff.

thanks